# Transfering data between two managed instance PostgreSQL Servers

Tags: postgresql, etl, transfer, dbeaver

I have two remote PostgreSQL servers on managed instances with no local OS that I can access. I want to copy a table from one to the other.

I have DBeaver on a laptop that allows me to set up connections to both servers. When I initiate a transfer job between them, I can see from ethernet traffic that the data is coming from the source remote server down to my laptop 'through' DBeaver and then back up to the target remote server. Two internet trips for the data.

Is there a way to avoid this double trip across the net for my data? Maybe some way of initiating a direct link between the two machines when I have no access to the OS or filesystem of either?
Thanks

Comment: Use foreign tables with a foreign data wrapper.

Comment: Nice, thanks AHWNN.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to a-horse-with-no-name for this solution.
As he says in the comments, use a foreign data wrapper.
This link helped me:
https://thoughtbot.com/blog/postgres-foreign-data-wrapper